# Highcharts bad rendering with slightly big numbers

Tags: highcharts

When I use multiaxes and big numbers, Highcharts renders double the height needed to show the data. How can I achieve fitting the vertical axis to the data correctly?

Here the example code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            crosshair: true
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°C',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
                }
            },
            opposite: true

        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} mm',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            }

        }, { // Tertiary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} mb',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [067416, 056716, 1554.9, 15546.5, 10412.3, 1009.5, 991009.6, 1010.2, 14563.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 2,
            data: [967416, 056716, 1554.9, 15546.5, 10412.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 14563.1, 991016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dashStyle: 'shortdot',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mb'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [067416, 056716, 1554.9, 15546.5, 10412.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 991010.2, 14563.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' °C'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/voqxkb3m/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `alignTicks: false` to your chart properties.

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/voqxkb3m/2/

You can adjust settings like `maxPadding` and `endOnTick` to further reduce the `yAxis` spacing.

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/voqxkb3m/3/

Comment: I already had `endOnTick: false`, but `maxPadding` and `minPadding` along with `alignTicks` solved it. I changed `endOnTick` to `true` and now the looks are awesome.